# PHYSICAL_READ_BYTES_DELTA and PHYSICAL_READ_BYTES_TOTAL

Tags: oracle, system-tables

What is the difference between `PHYSICAL_READ_BYTES_DELTA` column and `PHYSICAL_READ_BYTES_TOTAL`  column in `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` table? Are they correlate?  Please provide also an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_4051.htm) explains it perfectly:

> The total value is the value of the statistics since instance
>   startup. The delta value is the value of the statistics from the
>   BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME to the END_INTERVAL_TIME in the DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT
>   view.

So in this case, the `PHYSICAL_READ_BYTES_TOTAL` is the number of physical reads (in bytes) since the instance was started, and `PHYSICAL_READ_BYTES_DELTA` is the number of physical reads (in bytes) since the previous snapshot (`SNAP_ID`).

Comment: In the documentation referenced (10.1) in your answer the `DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT` does not have such columns. I seems that the column was added to this vies in 11g.

Comment: @miracle173 thanks, I didn't check. Just googled for a link :)